# Basic in environment(world) control

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there ! ,

Do you have any recommended method in order to

create the world that we can interact with it .

such as

- turn on , off the lights
- open , close the doors

manually and automatically with the script (py,C++ is alright) .

i have read through the tutorial and i cannot find the way to deal with it directly .

So , i decided to post here to be the reference for the guy who is new to the gazebo like me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13930/basic-in-environment(world)-control./) by [c3mx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2714/c3mx/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [c3mx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2714/c3mx/) on 2016-07-26**:
Actually , I intended to make the simulation of the smart home system. This may help my robot in controlling the smart things inside the home such as turning on , off the lightbulb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is how I achieve the light control .

Send message by using the  [STANDALONE PUBLISHER in GAZEBO REPO](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/2e153b94b73a5f3e6301cc65640920cdb311f08c/examples/stand_alone/publisher/?at=default)

and change the message type in the while loop to gazebo::msgs::Light (Need to include light message)

destination of accessing : existing light in .world file => So it has a name.

You can put the name onto the message's name field.

in order to control the light , I used lightMessage set range field . ( 0 = off , others = on )

then you can include ROS Node required file to do the controlling scheme.

---

Originally posted by [c3mx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2714/c3mx/) with karma: 1 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0